# How can I connect two goals to a page test?

Tags: content-testing, goals

When creating a page test in Sitecore Experience Optimization you can as test objective choose to connect either one specific goal or all your goals (trailing value/visit). Do any of you know about a possibility or work around to connect two specific goals to a page test in the Experience Optimization?

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you on?

Comment: Version: Sitecore 8.0

Answer (score 3):

If you go to your page test definition in the content editor under `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Test Lab` after the draft has been saved, you can see that there is a Conversion field that allows you to select multiple goals.  However, the Winner Strategy that is provided out-of-the-box, `Sitecore.ContentTesting.Analytics.WinnerStrategies.TestObjectiveBasedStrategy` only uses the first selection.  You would need to create a class that implements `Sitecore.ContentTesting.Analytics.WinnerStrategies.IWinnerStrategy` and add another `Test Winner Strategy`item under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Content Testing/Test Winner Strategies`.  You could then select that strategy on your test.

Note that the actual implementation of the strategy could be rather complicated. It will be different depending on if you want the user to achieve both goals, if achieving either is sufficient, if you wanted to use the values assigned to the goals, etc.